# Why does this postgresql bulk update statement with a with statement not work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

Why does this postgresql statement not work?

```
with updatedcontacts (contact_id, list_id, firstname) as 
 values (13680724,457,'James'),(13680723,457,'Stanley') 
update contacts c 
  set c.firstname = u.firstname 
from updatedcontacts u 
where u.contact_id = c.contact_id 
  and u.list_id = c.list_id;
```

Throws the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "values" LINE 52: ...updatedcontacts
> (contact_id, list_id, firstname) as values (
> ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 2944

Answer (score 2):

`values` should be wrapped in additional parentheses:

```
with updatedcontacts (contact_id, list_id, firstname) as 
    (values (13680724,457,'James'),(13680723,457,'Stanley'))
...
```

Comment: @Adronicus . . . Interesting.  I would phrase this as a CTE needs additional parentheses, but the effect is the same.